# How to customize DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver logic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, exception

I want to customize `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` in my Spring Boot application but custom implementation was never reached when exception was occurred.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok' version '1.14'
}

lombok {
    version = '1.18.4'
    sha256 = ""
}

group = 'ua.com.javaman'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
}
```

**Application.java**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@Configuration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping("/mouse")
    public Mouse postMouse(@Valid Mouse mouse) {
        // mouse creation logic
        return mouse;
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver customHandlerExceptionResolver() {
        return new CustomExceptionHandlerResolver();
    }
}
```

**Mouse.java**

```java
@Value
public class Mouse {
    private final Long id;
    @NotEmpty
    @Min(2)
    private final String name;
}
```

**CustomExceptionHandlerResolver.java**

```java
public class CustomExceptionHandlerResolver extends DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver {
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleBindException(
        BindException ex, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @Nullable Object handler
    ) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("In CustomExceptionHandlerResolver");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        return new ModelAndView();
    }
}
```

**Package structure**

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── ua
                └── com
                    └── javaman
                        └── exception_handling
                            ├── Application.java
                            ├── CustomExceptionHandlerResolver.java
                            └── Mouse.java
```

When I invoke application with wrong values for `Mouse` entity, for example,

```
POST localhost:8080/mouse?name=1
```

than [`handleBindException()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/78a6429c3295ecdbc35b064f7ebfa568079856df/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java#L488-L492) method in `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` is invoked but not in my `CustomExceptionHandlerResolver`.

**How can I handle `BindException` with my `CustomExceptionHandlerResolver`?**

Comment: are you missing `@Component` on `CustomExceptionHandlerResolver`

Comment: @Deadpool adding `@Component` have not resolved my problem

Comment: show the package structure also

Comment: @Deadpool I have added package structure

Answer (score 9):

SpringBoot 's auto configuration will always create [a bunch of exception handlers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html#addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers-java.util.List-) by default which one of them is `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` at order 0 (lower value has the higher priority) . Your handler by default will has lower priority than these default , so it will not be invoked as the exception is already handled by the default.

You can implement your configuration class with `WebMvcConfigurer` and override [extendHandlerExceptionResolvers()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#extendHandlerExceptionResolvers-java.util.List-) to modify the default settings. The idea is to  find out the `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` instance and replace it with yours.

But a better idea is to define your `CustomExceptionHandlerResolver` with `@ControllerAdvice` , which make sure that you will not mess up with the default settings while still add the customised behaviour that your want (i.e use your logic to handle `BindException`) :

```
@Component
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandlerResolver {

    @ExceptionHandler(value= BindException.class)
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleBindException(
            BindException ex, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @Nullable Object handler)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("In CustomExceptionHandlerResolver");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        return new ModelAndView();
    }

}
```

Comment: `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` or some other custom order could be used to make sure exception handler takes precedence.

Comment: Implement Ordered interface with the order less than 0 can take precedence over those default .  But to be precised , there are multiple default exception handlers at the order 0 while your custom exception handler basically will handle all the exceptions .If you make your handler  has higher priority over those default , you will override some of the default exception handling behaviour such as those @ExceptionHandler.....

Comment: `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` has order `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` in spring 5.3.3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. When you extend `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` do not forget to override the `getOrder` method. By default it returns the `LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`. To ensure that your implementation works first returns HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE.

DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver eats core exceptions and sometimes it's very hard to understand what happens when a client get 500 status code. To avoid this I used simple workaround.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ExceptionHandler extends DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver {
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
        var result = super.doResolveException(request, response, handler, ex);
        if (result != null) {
            log.warn("Request was finished with an error.", ex);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

Of course it's better to define a handler for each exception like [@Ken Chan][1] suggested
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976971/1259255